# How make a cross-browser custom list-style markers?

Tags: css

I need to make a custom list-style markers. Now it's done by adding element before li, but exist one problem. The remaining lines should be aligned with the text for the marker, such as normal marked list, but they don't.

```
li p::before {
    content: "* ";
}
```

How I make padding for second, third and etc lines, and make it cross-browser? (IE8+, FF3+, Opera 11+ and Crome)

Comment: Can't you use an image as list-style? I think it would be simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's umpossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li p:before { /* thanks Michael */
    content: "* ";
    float:left;
}
li p {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Maybe this will work. May I know why can't you use images (simple curiosity)?

EDIT: I was wrong, `:before` insert pseudo-element before **[content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after)**, so

```
<div id="wrap">

    <ul>

        <li><p>Get order of list items in a jQuery Sortable list after resort ... The trick is I would like to capture the order of the items immediately ... And I'm aware that it's also possible to assign a call-back function that fires when sorting st</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
#wrap
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li p
{
    overflow:auto;
}

li:before {
    content: "* ";
    float:left;
}
```

will work.

Comment: If you use `p:before` instead of `p::before` It will work in IE8 too. The new browser also supports the CSS2 way.

Comment: Right, I pasted without notice -_-

Comment: Perfect work and incredible tnx! Everybody else, can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/mbarinov/S8cvJ/

Comment: You're welcome! However true cross-browsers custom markers should be images =P

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the p and li to float: left; ([example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwuc/))

```
li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

li p
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or set the display to inline-block ([example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwuc/1/))

```
li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

li p
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Well of course it doesn't work, one `<li>` with multiple lines of text is not going to generate more than one bullet point, even without the custom markup. You'll need to split up each line into a separate li/p pair.